# Does MATLAB have a discontinous list?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB's list/array has continuous memory. So I guess appending/concatenation must require reallocation and data copy, although I am not sure if it reserves space internally.

Does MATLAB have a list with discontinuous memory so we can append elements with constant overhead? It has a containers.Map. Does it have constant access time? If so, I could use it to simulate a list.

Comment: Can you have discontinuous memory with constant access time? At the least you need a look-up table which may have to be reallocated? Or access is not constant. Or I'm missing something...

Comment: You are right about appending/concatenation, it does require reallocation and may slow your code down. I am not sure if containers.Map has a hashmap or a BST implementation, the documentation does not say anything about complexity

Comment: @zeeMonkeez: I meant a const-cost append time. I am fine if I have to access elements one by one in order. Could we actually define mex functions that internally use a list in C?

Comment: I am curious above where this went in the end?  It is a good question that I had contemplated a number of times, given Matlab's limited tools for building data structures (specially compared with C).

Comment: @zdim I implemented a std::vector-like cell by mex. So it has preallocated memory, and the memory is reallocated when it reaches the maximal size,

Comment: Nice :).  Thank you for feedback.  (I once had to do write MEX for performance, to avoid huge data copies -- which can nicely be avoided via pointer manipulations ... in C. It worked well.)

Comment: @JoeC  I was reviewing some older posts of mine and ran into this, and have a comment.  I'd suggest that you make your comment above into a post and mark that as answer, for future visitors to this interesting question. It's OK if it's a simple two-line comment, if that's the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a std::vector-like cell by mex. So it has preallocated memory, and the memory is reallocated when it reaches the maximal size.

Answer (score 2):

Based on clarifications, I would go with either `containers.Map`, or with a `Cell Array` if it is feasible to write your own routine that would grow it infrequently, in larger steps (double it every time, say). Which one I'd choose would depend on what is being done, since working with them is rather different.

---

There are two data structures that come close, and another solution.

- [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html).  I am not sure about the exact complexity, and I never found firm statements about it. It should be a hash table, so in principle you should have `O(1)`.  However, I don't know that you'll get exactly constant under all conditions. This may be what you want to use if you cannot allocate ahead of time, or if it is not feasible to double  (or so) the size as needed.
- Cell array.  In my experience it is a near equivalent of an array with pointers, with access time as one would expect, regardless of what is inside. I don't know what complexity is claimed.   Cell arrays come in various kinds, and performance will depend, see for example [this page on Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/homogeneous-vs-heterogeneous-cell-arrays.html?refresh=true) about differences between types of cell arrays.  It informs us that the generated code will be either a C array or a C structure.  I think that one can safely infer performance from that.
- Yes, you can implement in MEX any of it, if you are up for that.

---

You can ask for memory to be booked upfront: Set up your structure of the needed size. If you have no values that make sense to initialize, empty it using an according assignment (for example, `= []` for an array etc).  This is what I do.  You can do this periodically, as needed (in loops for example).  There should be no data copy or new memory allocations.

Comment: I use C-like list in my question, which has constant overhead when adding elements at tail and head. I think cell array is similar to ordinary array but can contain any type. So assigning new elements outside its bound still results in reallocation, does not it? Or I missed anything.

Comment: @JoeC According to a refresher i just ran, your closest match is `containers.Map`, which is a hash table after all, with expected `O(1)` complexity.  (However, I don't know that you'll always get a constant.)

Comment: @JoeC Well, correct. Can you pre-allocate a needed size? You mention that possibility.